# Serializing a class containing a non-serializable class

Tags: java, serialization

I have two classes, `A` and `B`.

Class `A` is developed by X company and is not serializable.

Company Y is trying to use class `A` in class `B`, which must be serializable.

How can this be done without changing class `A`? Is that what the externalization interface is for?

Comment: I've cleaned up your question so it's a bit more clear, but you really need to show that you've made a good faith effort to solve your problem - we aren't here to do your work for you, we're here to help when you run into a specific problem.

Answer (score 5):

Sure. You need to make fields in your class `B` referring to their class `A` `transient` (or use `serialPersistentFields` if I've spelt that correctly). Implement custom `writeObject` and `readObject` methods in `B` to save the required state of `A` in serialisable objects.

There is no need for `Externalizable` (pretty much ever).

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by @Tom Hawtin - tackline You have two ways to combat this situation:
**1.** *Declare the instance variable of class A as transient..*

```
private transient A a ;
```

Or,
**2.** By using `serialPersistentFields`. This instructs the JVM to persist only those fields which it has mentioned. Here is a short example:

```
public class B implements Serializable
{
    private A a;
    private String name ;
    private int enrollment;
    private static final ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields = 
        {
            new ObjectStreamField("name",String.class),
            new ObjectStreamField("enrollment",int.class)
        }; //This will cause only "name" and "enrollment" to persist while serialization

}
```

Comment: @Bruno Reis thanks for rectifying the typo but critical mistake :)

Comment: That's not a useful misspelling of `serialPersistentFields` (or however it's spelt). There really ought to be an `@Serial` or similar annotation for these things. / You are probably going to want to serialise and deserialise state contained within `a`.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline:Yeah agreed with your point.. `@Serial` would be a better workaround because that would enforce compile time checking and won't let the program to compile until spelled correctly unlike `serialPersistentField`(oops forget to add `s` in last) ;).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done by implementing `java.io.Externalizable` - it allows you to implement serialization manually, by writing individual bytes (or more conveniently through methods like `writeInt()`). As long as you can get *and set* all information about an instance of class `A` from its public API, you can simply embed it into your custom serialized representation of classs `B`.

Comment: You don't need to use `Externalizable`. Custom `readObject` and `writeObject` methods are sufficient.